# How can I step through a winforms application including after any button is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, debugging

How can I step through a winforms application including after any button is clicked?

Sometimes i'm interested in stepping through my program from start to finish.

I can start by hitting F10,  I don't have to put any breakpoints in. After a few taps of F10, Form1 appears.

Now let's say Form1 has a button and when the button is clicked it runs some code.

If I click that button, it doesn't go back into debug mode and into the code.

I don't want to have to put a breakpoint in every button click.

How can I make it so that when I click any button, it goes into the code for it.

So that I can continue stepping through my program with F10 and F11, from start to finish.

e.g. F10,F10,F10  Form1 Loads with the button. I click the button.  F10, F10..

e.t.c

Rather than the current situation where I click a button and it continues with the program until it hits a breakpoint.

Comment: Not possible, only with breakpoint

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  Is it express?

Comment: @dbasnett 2015 not express

Comment: Start with the function key assigned to Step Into.  I believe that as long as you are using only one of the 'Step" functions you should get the desired results.

Comment: I tried it and it did work.  If you search MSDN you will find that there are cases where it doesn't work based on your environment.

Comment: MSDN search https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=visual%20studio%20debug%20F10%20not%20working&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search%20MSDN&ac=5

Comment: @dbasnett you're onto something, that an F11 at the point before the form loads will do it. But it means stepping into a lot more code that i'd want to step into.

Comment: @dbasnett I think maybe what I might do is put a breakpoint where on the first form load. Fine i'll miss the code that launches that form but that's internal code im' not interested in seeing anyway. And i guess i'd see any subsequent forms that are loaded.. i'll test that to make sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116682/discussion-between-barlop-and-dbasnett).

Comment: I'm off to work so it will have to be later.

Comment: @dbasnett What I wrote in the link you replied to, was "Thanks.. your comments led me to a good solution"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out based on comment from dbasnett

The code that launches Form1 / the first form, is very internal code. You don't even see it with F11. It happens after Form1 is loaded, and you don't see any particular line of code that runs that make it appear.

One solution and it's not a good one, is to start debugging with F10 or F11, and ensure that the key you hit before Form1 appears, is F11. Then, when you click the button, you'll be able to step through.

A much easier / better solution, is to put one single breakpoint in. You can put it on Form1 load. That is before the form appears too. And then start debugging with Play. When it hits the breakpoint then you can do F10s or F11s or any mix. It will bring up the form. And this time when you click a button, it will continue in debugging mode and you can use F10 or F11 or whatever mix.

Comment: so can put a breakpoint at the closing brace of Form1 load and hit F11.  Then when you click a button it will step through